File system is very slow on both my drives
I'm having a strange problem with trying to load things off my drives on Ubuntu 22.04.3. My computer has a 2TB NVMe SSD as its boot drive and a 14 TB hard drive that I store data on. I'm not physically by my computer, but I'm remoting in with RustDesk (I do this all the time and have never had a problem).
Today, however, my storage is too slow to function right. My hard drive won't load at all. I can cd around in terminal, but it just endlessly loads when I try to open in files. I also can't use ls to list files in terminal once I get into a folder. My boot drive loads alright, but it super slow to read files. I tried to open a simple text file that is 80 bytes and it took around 30 seconds to open.
I had a friend in the office restart the computer, but nothing changed. Any ideas? Should I just turn it off and let it calm down overnight? Any ideas are appreciated.
Edit: I forgot to mention. I can't unmount the hard drive, I get a "target is busy" message. As far as I'm aware, it shouldn't be doing anything. I would like to avoid forcefully unmounting for fear of data loss.

Can't say that I have a clue what the problem could be.  I doubt leaving the system off overnight would be better than something much shorter however, it might be worth it to try:


So something from the command line that takes more than 5 seconds -


Do this again but this time, prefix it with the command time


Note the three resulting times (user, sys and real)


Power off the system for a minimum of 30 seconds, perhaps 2 minutes.


Power the system back on


Again do that command with time in front and observe any differences



Please add to your question the results of the free command. Full system buffers can slow everything down,. Does the top command show any process getting an excess of cpu?  Does iotop show any process doing a lot of IO?  Do you have any indication on your disks of activity (light, noise,...)?

Look into the system logs. journalctl -xeb.
